# Bitmaps saved in array are deleted after accessing them

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to loop an array of bitmaps, but it will only show it once and then the array is empty. You can actually see it at the RAM usuage that deletes the last accessed bitmap from the array.

The code:

```
 CurrentBuffer++;

 var temp = bitmaparray[CurrentBuffer];

 if (pictureBox1.Image != null) { 
   pictureBox1.Image.Dispose(); 
 }

 if (CurrentBuffer == BufferFrames) 
   CurrentBuffer = 1;   // bufferframes is the total count of elements -1 in the array

 pictureBox1.Image = temp;

 // attempt to put the image back in the array again, but still doesn't work
 bitmaparray[CurrentBuffer] = temp;
```

The desired result is that it will show the bitmaps in chronological order over and over again. But now it will loop through it once and then the array is empty.

What am I missing here?

Comment: BTW: You are only playing with references. So you are actually disposing the images by yourself.

Comment: @UweKeim I will look in to that! Thanks for the super quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

At each iteration, you assign the image to `pictureBox1.Image`.

```
pictureBox1.Image = temp;
```

Then in the next iteration, you call dispose on that image:

```
pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
```

Here, `pictureBox1.Image` is pointing back to the image in your `bitmaparray`, so you are actually disposing in the image from the array.

I think you just need to get rid of the Dispose.

(this is all based on Uwe Keim's comment, thanks)